# Triacs other components resistors and capacitor as switch

Tags: components, triac

[image]

Found this circuit on the [internet](https://innovatorsguru.com/switching-ac-load-using-triac/) but they don't elaborate the much.

I understand other components function except for **R2, R3, and C1**.
Can somebody explain them?

As for my understanding,

- R1 - to limit current coming to optocoupler
- Optocoupler to isolate two voltage source
- Triac - to switch AC voltage ON-OFF
- R4 and C2 - as snubber to eliminate spikes from inductive loads

Comment: Most likely the article writer has just copied the circuit from somewhere and does not understand either. Have you looked at MOC3021 datasheet, which usually contains example circuits how to use the component?

Comment: Here you will find the answer https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00451014-controlling-a-triac-with-a-phototriac-stmicroelectronics.pdf  In short R3 + R2 limits, the optotriac current and C1 together with resistors form a low pass filter to prevent false triggers by a rapid coltage change.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on datasheet as suggested on comment section

[image]